# Render view is different from texture view

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers, renderman-render-engine

I have imported a mode to blender and i am using Cycles Render.
When i switch my viewport to Texture mode it shows textures just fine as shown in the image below[image]

But when i switch to Renderer Mode it does not show the character with textures.here is image of Render View
[image]

This is how character looks in material view
[image]

I Want my character to look in render view like it is in texture view.

Comment: Welcome to Blender SE. I don't see a light in your scene. Try adding a sun lamp and face it toward the model.

Comment: In the world tab add some environment image